# Why is not a solar plate ionised?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

When sunlight is allowed to incident on a solar cell, photons are absorbed and electron hole pair are produced in P and N regions. The electrons and the holes generated over a small distance from the junction can reach the depletion layer of weight W by diffusion. The electrons and holes are separated by the various field across the depleted layer. The electrons from P side can move towards the N side and the holes from the Nside can move towards the Pside.This is why we get electricity from a solar cell.But if this process continue then one day all the electrons will eject from the solar cell and it is also ionised..but this doesn't happen..but why?

Answer (score 0):

You already stated that the absorption of photons in the solar cell creates electron-hole pairs, i.e. a positive and a negative elementary charge.  In the current generated by the cell for each negative electron exiting one contact, a positive hole goes to the other contact. Thus charge neutrality is maintained and the cell will not be charged or ionized.

Comment: Okay.But if this process continues then one day all the electrons will flow towards the hole and one day if we will contact it with sun light,then no electrons will flow through the external circuit.But this doesn't happen.why?

Comment: @user196658 - The  generated electrons flowing  out of one contact return to the other contact where they recombine with the holes. Thus when a current flows in the solar cell, the number of electrons leaving  the cell per unit time is the same as are returning to  the cell. Therefore during the operation of the solar cell no electrons will be lost.